# Using Powershell to remove a user from a list of groups

Tags: powershell

Trying to get this script to remove a user from a list of groups.

Not sure what part of my language here is wrong. It doesn't return an error in ISE. I'm admittedly a rookie in writing my own powershell scripts instead of modifying others. Any help is appreciated.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$group = @('grouopname1','groupname2','groupname3')
$user = "testa"

if ($user.Memberof -like $group)
{
    foreach ($user in $group )
    {
     Remove-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -identity $user -MemberOf $group -confirm:$False
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On thing you'll need to learn when using PowerShell is that it's very important to test what kind of output and object will give you.

```
$user = "testa" | $user.MemberOf
```

That will give you an error, because a string doesn't have a member property "MemberOf"

```
$user = Get-ADUser testa -Properties MemberOf
```

That will give you an object containing the user "testa", and since the MemberOf property isn't retrieved by default, you will need to add it in.

```
$user.MemberOf
```

This will return the DistinguishedName of all groups that the user is a member of, but it will not get nested groups... that would require more logic, but you can find that if you search for it.

Your group array would work... if you do a replace on $user.MemberOf so that it only returns the Common Name, but you can easily just compare the DNs. To do that however, you would need to do something like this:

```
$groups = $group | foreach ($g in $group) { Get-ADGroup $g }
```

Not pretty, but it will get you there.

The final part of the loop can be something like this:

```
foreach ($u in ($user.MemberOf))
{
    if (($groups.DistinguishedName) -Contains $u)
    {
        Do-Whatever
    }
}
```

I would generally start with a test inside the loop, using Write-Host or -WhatIf to verify just what was going to be done.

Comment: Thanks this really helped. Got it running now!

Comment: Glad you got it. One of the things I learned early with PowerShell was to verify what TYPE your object is, and then how is it formatting the output.

Comment: Yeah I just picked up this book "learn powershell in 30 days of lunches" and i've got a course on it downloaded. But doing things in the field and learning what works and what doesn't is always super useful. Glad there are helpful people out there on the internet though! Thanks again.

Comment: Check out the courses on MicrosoftVirtualAcademy as well, there is a really good intro course.